# What's the difference between location /path and location ^~ /path?

Tags: nginx

Is it just that nginx will always consider prefix paths matched with ^~ first?

If that is the case can I use ^~ to speed up my location selection if I have a lot of them?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location shows the logic nginx uses when matching `location` blocks.

The difference between `/path` and `^~ /path` is that nginx doesn't check regex locations with the latter one. So, if you have regex location blocks, then it makes things a bit faster.

Comment: Yes it was after I read that that I was confused. Does that imply it they are the same in every other way?